# R: dccfit error: length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

Tags: r

Im trying to run the dccfit function for some stock returns in order to model the covariance matrix.

In the model documentation its recommended to use a an xts object.
I found an example of how to run the function with a data frame under the bellow link and the example works. 
But when I try to run it with my own data set I do not get it to work. 
http://www.unstarched.net/2013/01/03/the-garch-dcc-model-and-2-stage-dccmvt-estimation/ 
https://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ589/DCCgarchPowerpoint.pdf

I have tried to change the dimnames and the rownames without result

```
library(zoo)
library(rugarch)
library(xts)
library(rmgarch)

getSymbols(Symbols = c("^GSPC", "SPN"), 
       env = parent.frame(),
       reload.Symbols = FALSE,
       verbose = FALSE,
       warnings = TRUE,
       src = "yahoo",
       symbol.lookup = TRUE,
       auto.assign = getOption('getSymbols.auto.assign',TRUE),
       from = "1927-01-01",
       to = "2018-04-28")

GSPC_dataframe <- data.frame(date=index(GSPC), coredata(GSPC))

## SPECIFYING DCC GARCH
# univariate normal GARCH(1,1) for each series
garch11.spec = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0,0)),variance.model = list(garchOrder = c(1,1),model = "sGARCH"),distribution.model = "norm")
# dcc specification - GARCH(1,1) for conditional correlations
dcc.garch11.spec = dccspec(uspec = multispec( replicate(2, garch11.spec) ),dccOrder = c(1,1),distribution = "mvnorm")
dcc.garch11.spec

## ESTIMATE DCC GARCH data needs to be a dataframe
# I have tried to see if idderent options work
dcc.fit = dccfit(dcc.garch11.spec, data = GSPC$LogReturn)
dcc.fit = dccfit(dcc.garch11.spec, data = GSPC_dataframe$LogReturn)
dcc.fit = dccfit(dcc.garch11.spec, data = GSPC)
dcc.fit = dccfit(dcc.garch11.spec, data = GSPC_dataframe)
```

I have tried to run the function with both an its object and a data frame and I'm getting the same error:

```
"Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent"
```

Grateful for any help or direction!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what a 'dccfit function' is, and it seems like your method is unnecessarily complex.  Anyway, if you want a basic correlation matrix and covariance matrix, the script below will do it for you.

```
library(quantmod)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

symbols <- c("AAPL", "MSFT", "GOOG")
getSymbols(symbols)
stocks <- data.frame(as.xts(merge(AAPL, MSFT, GOOG)))
stocks$date <- row.names(stocks)
row.names(stocks) <- NULL

# head(stocks)

jan31 <- ymd("2018-01-31")
days_to_keep <- jan31 %m+% months(0:11)
# days_to_keep

res <- stocks %>%
  select(ends_with("Close"), date) %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
  filter(date %in% days_to_keep)

# correlation matrix:
res %>% select(-date) %>% cor()

#            AAPL.Close MSFT.Close GOOG.Close
# AAPL.Close  1.0000000  0.9198357  0.9313001
# MSFT.Close  0.9198357  1.0000000  0.9103830
# GOOG.Close  0.9313001  0.9103830  1.0000000

# Or more visually...
res %>% select(-date) %>% pairs()


# covariance matrix:
res %>% select(-date) %>% cov()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line:

```
GSPC_dataframe <- data.frame(date=index(GSPC), coredata(GSPC))
```

You should extract the closing prices from both datasets and merge them into one xts time series:

```
data <- cbind(Cl(GSPC), Cl(SPN))
```

Than you can run the `dccfit` like this:

```
dcc.fit = dccfit(dcc.garch11.spec, data)
```

A look at your data with `head(GSPC)` or `head(SPN)` will give you some idea why this was not working.